# Compensate for Safari's Border Radius Drawing

Tags: css, safari

Observe the below simple example:

```css
div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

In Safari, this causes part of the upper borders to be drawn:
[image: Safari's drawing of a border radius]

I don't want those "ghosted" upper borders. How do I compensate for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the rounded border on the top side of your `div` like so:

```
div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0 0 20% 20%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

This is using the `border-radius` shorthand with 4 values where

> first value applies to top-left, second value applies to top-right,
>   third value applies to bottom-right, and fourth value applies to
>   bottom-left corner"

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: Huh, weird that a border-radius is drawn for a border that has no width. But you're right: setting the upper values explicitly to "0" did the trick. Don't know why I didn't think of that... Thanks!